# Removing leading whitespace from indented HTML source in pre/code tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I currently have the following html within a pre-code block:

```
                <pre class="prettyprint"><code>
                    &lt;html&gt;
                    &lt;body&gt;

                    &lt;form name=&quot;input&quot; action=&quot;html_form_action.asp&quot; method=&quot;get&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;input type=&quot;radio&quot; name=&quot;sex&quot; value=&quot;male&quot;&gt;Male&lt;br&gt;
                    &lt;input type=&quot;radio&quot; name=&quot;sex&quot; value=&quot;female&quot;&gt;Female&lt;br&gt;
                    &lt;input type=&quot;submit&quot; value=&quot;Submit&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;/form&gt; 

                    &lt;p&gt;If you click the &quot;Submit&quot; button, the form-data will be sent to a page called &quot;html_form_action.asp&quot;.&lt;/p&gt;

                    &lt;/body&gt;
                    &lt;/html&gt;
                </code></pre>
```

It is indented within the html source for better structure within the document. How can I remove the leading whitespace? Through the use of javascript or is there a more simple method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to just change how it is output, but it is fairly simple to do with JavaScript

```
var p = document.querySelector(".prettyprint");
p.textContent = p.textContent.replace(/^\s+/mg, "");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4gfZ/

Comment: Thank you it worked exactly the way i wanted it! Just a general question is it more preferable for viewers to have the code wrap or for it just flow and scroll through?

Comment: @Deep I'd personally prefer it to wrap

Comment: Solves the particular example, but if the code itself is indented it would lose that indent.

Comment: Because of @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功's comment, this answer isn't really a solution to the problem. It's just a monkeypatch for this particular manifestation of the problem.

Answer (score 60):

The question asks if there's a JavaScript solution or a simpler method for removing leading whitespace. There's a simpler method:

**CSS**

```
pre, code {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/puy8gv5r/)

> [**white-space**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
>
> The `white-space` property is used to describe how whitespace inside the
> element is handled.
>
> ***pre-line***
>
> Sequences of whitespace are collapsed.

To preserve existing whitespace or indentation, each line can be wrapped in a child tag with `white-space` reset to `pre` at the line level:

**HTML**

```
<pre>
    <code>
        <i>fn main() {</i>
        <i>    println!("hello world!");</i>
        <i>}</i>
    </code>
</pre>
```

**CSS**

```
pre, code {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

pre > code > i {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: It removes non-leading repeated whitespace characters as well, which might not be desirable: http://jsfiddle.net/0zLv0nod/

Comment: I want to remove whitespace on just the first line of a pretty printed json string and this solution removes indent from every line of the string.  :-(

Comment: @djangofan Put the indent for each line within the child tag.

Answer (score 10):

I really like Homam's idea, but I had to change it to deal with this:

```
<pre><code><!-- There's nothing on this line, so the script thinks the indentation is zero -->
    foo = bar
</code></pre>
```

To fix it, I just take out the first line if it's empty:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('code'), function($code) {
    var lines = $code.textContent.split('\n');

    if (lines[0] === '')
    {
        lines.shift()
    }

    var matches;
    var indentation = (matches = /^[\s\t]+/.exec(lines[0])) !== null ? matches[0] : null;
    if (!!indentation) {
        lines = lines.map(function(line) {
            line = line.replace(indentation, '')
            return line.replace(/\t/g, '    ')
        });

        $code.textContent = lines.join('\n').trim();
    }
});
```

(I'm also processing `<code>` tags instead of `<pre>` tags.)

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed, a nice modification to @homam's answer

Comment: Your answer can end at first code block, that snippet open my eyes...

Comment: I moved `$code.textContent = lines.join('\n').trim();` outside of the if statement to trim out a blank line even if the first line after that does not have indentation.

Answer (score 8):

Extending the above solution, this snippet assumes the indentation of the the first line inside `<pre>` is 0 and it realigns all the lines based on the first line:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('pre'), function($pre) {
  var lines = $pre.textContent.split('\n');
  var matches;
  var indentation = (matches = /^\s+/.exec(lines[0])) != null ? matches[0] : null;
  if (!!indentation) {
    lines = lines.map(function(line) {
      return line.replace(indentation, '');
    });
    return $pre.textContent = lines.join('\n').trim();
  }
});
```

Comment: For me, this answer is the first one to actually solve the problem.

Comment: This does, however, strip HTML content (for formatting etc.) from the <pre> tag, which isn't desirable

Comment: If you replace the instances of textContent with innerHTML, this does fix the issue. It will be slower to run though, if that's a concern.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `pre`, you should format its content to be exactly as you want it to be rendered. That’s the very idea of `pre` (preformatted text). But if it’s just indentation, you could use CSS: `margin-left` with a suitable negative value.

Comment: Only this solution worked for me.  white-space: pre-line css put every line starting from left most which I don't want for my rest of the lines.